# How to check if a directory containing a file exist?

Tags: groovy

I am using `groovy` to create a file like `"../A/B/file.txt"`. To do this, I have created a `service` and pass the `file path` to be created as an `argument`. This service is then used by a `Job`. The `Job` will do the logic in creating the file in the specified directory. I have manually created the "A" directory.

How will I create the "B" directory and the file.txt inside the "A" directory through codes to create it automatically?

I need also to check if directories "B" and "A" exists before creating the file.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

To check if a folder exists or not, you can simply use the `exists()` method:

```
// Create a File object representing the folder 'A/B'
def folder = new File( 'A/B' )

// If it doesn't exist
if( !folder.exists() ) {
  // Create all folders up-to and including B
  folder.mkdirs()
}

// Then, write to file.txt inside B
new File( folder, 'file.txt' ).withWriterAppend { w ->
  w << "Some text\n"
}
```

Comment: Note this is vulnerable to a race condition because another process can create the directory between the `.exists()` and `.mkdirs()` calls. I don’t know how to do that in Groovy, but in general the correct way is to create the directories and ignore the error if they already exist.

Comment: Pedant's corner: It isn't advised to "ignore" errors, period; rather, to handle them appropriately.  Even if that means a simple log recognising that some other thread has beaten your thread to it.

Answer (score 8):

EDIT: as of Java8 you'd better use [`Files`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createDirectories(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...)) class:

```
Path resultingPath = Files.createDirectories('A/B');
```

I don't know if this ultimately fixes your problem but class `File` has method [`mkdirs()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdirs%28%29) which fully creates the path specified by the file.

```
File f = new File("/A/B/");
f.mkdirs();
```

Comment: Thanks. But how will I create file.txt simultaneously with the creation of the directories?

Comment: I understand now, it should be f.mkdrs() since I am creating multiple directories. Thanks.